# Odd FaceTime stream microphone issue

Tags: ipad

I receive a live football stream via FaceTime on my iPad but the sender can hear sounds feedback from my lounge despite the microphone toggle showing mute. How can
I ensure no sound sent back from my iPad?

Comment: there was a bug in FaceTime that allowed people to here the other side, without them picking up the call. please update the Q with iOS version, and check for any update.

Comment: That is not the issue! iOS 13.1

Comment: what do you mean by receive a live stream via FaceTime ?

Comment: I connect via FT to my brother who streams his TV screen to my FT (BT footy)